# Unable to access weblogic admin console page

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x

I was making changes to configuration file in weblogic console form page. 
I selected lock and edit --> deployments and was making changes.
I refreshed the page from then on I am unable to connect to the weblogic console form page.

```
<Mar 23, 2012 1:25:20 PM EDT> <Error> <Kernel> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java/lang/NullPointerException, size 32B.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java/lang/NullPointerException, size 32B
at weblogic.management.configuration.OverloadProtectionMBeanImpl.getPanicAction(OverloadProtectio    nMBeanImpl.java:183)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means that weblogic could not find enough memory to complete the task. You may want to add the following parameters to your Weblogic startup command in setWeblogicEnv.cmd, restart weblogic  and try editing the parameters thru the console again. Please refer to [Weblogic reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html) under 'Specifying Heap Size Values' section for more info.

`-Xms512m -Xmx512m`  ---Increase the memory to more if you can for weblogic.